# Openxava simple application error

Tags: tomcat, openxava

I am trying to run my first openxava application. I have only one file with 4 fields. I am using Tomcat and Mssql server. I build the project, run and deploy everything goes allright..I use jd1.7 now. Before I tried with 1.8 I got the same error.

These are my fields:
    @Id @Required
    private Integer kifid;
        @Column(length=1)
    private String kisifirma;

```
@Column(length=1)
private String gonullumu;

@Column(length=50) 
private String tckno;

sql structure is like this :

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sekreterya_kisifirma](
[kifid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[kisifirma] [char](1) NULL,
[Gonullumu] [int] NULL,
[TCKNo] [varchar](50) NULL, .....
```

when I try to reach my module from browser this exception comes.. I feel that it should be an easy to solve problem. But I need some help..

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 7 in the generated java file 
The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /xava/module.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
29:                     || "xava.portlet.module".equals(name))
30:                 continue;
31:             String value = request.getParameter(name);
32:             result.append('&');
33:             result.append(name);
34:             result.append('=');
35:             result.append(value);


An error occurred at line: 165 in the jsp file: /xava/module.jsp
Arrays cannot be resolved
162:    <%
163:        File jsEditorsFolder = new File(realPath + "/xava/editors/js");     
164:        String[] jsEditors = jsEditorsFolder.list();
165:        Arrays.sort(jsEditors);
166:        for (int i = 0; i < jsEditors.length; i++) {
167:            if (jsEditors[i].endsWith(".js")) {
168:    %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.openxava.web.servlets.ModuleServlet.doGet(ModuleServlet.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 logs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there were multiple persistence unit in persistence.xml and one more format error in the same file. When I correct them I don't get the same error any more.

:)

Ferda

Comment: You can have all the persistence units you want in persistence.xml. Your problem is related with missing basic Java classes. I think that the problem was solved when you redeployed or cleaned your server.

Comment: No I am sure my problem was with persistence.xml :) There were problems on it. I tried to redeploy it before but it didn't effect. Anyway thank you four your interest. I liked this openxava framework. I think I will need help from you in the future  ..

Comment: Maybe you are right it may allow more than one persistence units but when I cleared the persistence.xml I also noticed there was a format error and I fixed it and problem didn't occured any more :)

Comment: You can get a lot of help on OpenXava in its official Help Forum. Try it.

Comment: Hi,I tried to post to forum in openxava. But i didn't allowed me to create a topic saying "You do not have permission to post in any forums." :(

Comment: You need to create an account in sourceforge.

Comment: Now you can find it in github https://github.com/openxava/openxava